# The perpendicular distance from a point to a line

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vectors, cross-product

The problem is as follows.

(i) $P$ be a point not on the line $L$ that passes through the points $Q$ and $R$. Show that the distance $d$ from the point $P$ to the line $L$ is

$$d = \frac{\|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\|}{\|\vec{b}\|}$$

where $\vec{a}=\vec{QR}$ and $\vec{b}=\vec{QP}$.

(ii) Use this formula to find the distance from the point $(-2,3)$ to the line $3x-4y+5=0$.

My calculations for (i) are as follows.

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

$$\sin{\theta} = \frac{d}{\|\vec{b}\|}$$

$$d = \|\vec{b}\|\sin{\theta} = \frac{\|\vec{a}\|\|\vec{b}\|\sin{\theta}}{\|\vec{a}\|} = \frac{\|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\|}{\|\vec{a}\|}$$

This value for $d$ is different from the value given in the problem. Have I made a calculatory mistake or is the problem's assertion incorrect?

Secondly, I don't understand (ii). Is the cross product possible for 2-dimensional vectors? If so, how is it calculated? And if it isn't, does this problem have to be solved using $d = \|\vec{b}\|\sin{\theta}$ or is there another method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right. The denominator should be $\|a\|.$ Draw pictures to convince yourself.

Comment: @AnilBagchi Oh okay. I have drawn pictures, and that's why I was so sure of that being the denominator. Thank you.

Comment: For (ii) find any two points on the straight line. Name them $Q$ and $R$ and apply the revised formula you obtained. Take $Q = (1,2)$ and $R = (-3,-1)$ for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About i) You are in fact correct, as can easily be verified using by example.

About ii) In fact the cross product is usually defined on $\mathbb R^3$, but it has an equivalent in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq 2$. For $n=2$ this is simply the map $(x,y)\to(y,-x)$. But you can simply embed the problem into $\mathbb R^3$ by setting a $z$ value to $0$ (obviously this does then not affect the distance).

Comment: I have tried to embed this into $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I found that the $z$ values being 0 gives me a result from the cross product where $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{k}$ both equal 0, leaving me only with a $\hat{j}$ term, which doesn't fit in the 2-d plane. What am I missing? Can I still take the magnitude of that vector with only the $\hat{j}$ term? Thanks.

Comment: @Alex The cross product as vector always stands orthogonal to it’s arguments. So projecting the result back onto $\mathbb R^2$ will not work in any way. But you do not need to do this! Once you’ve embedded your problem into $\mathbb R^3$ stay in $\mathbb R^3$ and do your calculations there! You can do this as $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,0)$ is an isometric embedding (also you’re only interested in the absolute value of the cross product, so after calculating the cross product all further calculations are in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Alright, I did that and I got $\frac{13}{5}$. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex This result seems to be correct.